# Spring Web App with Maven dependency - class not found during deploy

Tags: java, spring, maven, web-deployment-project, pom.xml

I'm having project named car-rental which contains business logic (built with maven). I use this project as dependency in other project named car-rental. It's declared as :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.car.rental</groupId>
        <artifactId>car-rental-model</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

During compilation in IDE Eclipse car-rental see all classes from dependency. But after deploy to Java EE container (for example GlassFish) classes aren't seen. Deployed project in server doesn't contain dependency classes.

car-rental project doesn't contains any specific build definitions:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

After maven packaging, car-rental-1.0 in target directory, contains required classes from business dependency.

Here's my car-rental project structure:

[image]

Probably I should somehow link business dependency in pom.xml file, but I have no idea how... Or maybe I thining wrong?

---

UPDATE

car-rental-model is packaged as *.jar file

```
<groupId>com.car.rental</groupId>
<artifactId>car-rental-model</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>car-rental-model</name>
```

car-rental is packaged as *.war file

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.car.rental</groupId>
<artifactId>car-rental</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

---

UPDATE 2

To give more info about project I put configuration files:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
      id="CarRental" version="2.5">
      <display-name>CarRental</display-name>
      <context-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
      </context-param>
      <context-param>
          <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/configs/log4j.properties</param-value>
      </context-param>
      <context-param>
          <param-name>log4jRefreshInterval</param-name>
          <param-value>1000</param-value>
      </context-param>
      <listener>
          <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
      </listener>
      <listener>
          <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
      </listener>
      <filter>
          <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
          <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
          <init-param>
              <param-name>encoding</param-name>
              <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
          </init-param>
          <init-param>
              <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
              <param-value>true</param-value>
          </init-param>
      </filter>
      <filter-mapping>
          <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
          <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>
      <servlet>
          <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
          <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
      <welcome-file-list>
          <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
  </web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml contains only references to other configuration files, which stores only configurations to Tiles, controllers or DAO implementations - it's rather not important to place here... maybe except Hibernate mapping:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
            hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
            hibernate.connection.charSet=UTF-8
            hibernate.bytecode.provider=javassist
            hibernate.show_sql=true
            hibernate.format_sql=true
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.car.rental.model.Car</value>
            <value>com.car.rental.model.User</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: This car-rental project is a module used in some other part? If so, run `mvn clean install` and car-rental should be installed into your internal maven repository and than used when you compile the main project.

Comment: You refer by the name 'car-rental' to two projects, mind clearing that up? What are the packagings of these projects (war/jar)? Also I don't think you need assembly plugin, I'd avoid it unless there is a really good reason.

Comment: @Tomas car-rental isn't a submodule of any other project

Comment: @mrembisz I've updated topic, maybe now it's more clear:)

Comment: did you by any chance solved your problem two years after ? I'm facing the exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

I think your configuration could look like this

`Car rental model`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.car.rental</groupId>
    <artifactId>car-rental-model</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <!-- dependencies ... -->

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

`Car rental`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.car.rental</groupId>
    <artifactId>car-rental</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.car.rental</groupId>
            <artifactId>car-rental-model</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- other dependencies -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I use the same configuration in all my projects and it works fine. If all of them have the `maven-compiler-plugin`, I will prefer creating a parent containing the common parts.

Comment: Doesn't work. As I said it's not trouble with compilation, it's trouble with dependecies which aren't found on server  after deploy `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/car/rental/model/User
 at com.car.rental.controllers.user.RegisterController.handleRequestInternal(RegisterController.java:28)`

Comment: Ok. Please do the following. Check your war archive if the `User.class` is there - `war archive -> WEB-INF -> lib -> car-rental-model.jar` or similar path. If so, please provide your Spring configuration.

Comment: War archive contains car-rental-model.jar and inside of *.jar there is User.class. Could you tell please what kind of Spring configuration I should give?

Comment: Do you have `applicationContext.xml` or something like that? How do you initialize your web application? You must have a `web.xml` where you load the context...

Comment: One more thing. Could you show me the `User.java` and `RegisterController.java`?

Comment: There's nothing special... I don't know how it could help you... Funcionality of project is correctly implemented. If I place all sources from car-rental-model to car-rental everything is OK. Trouble is caused by something with linking of project. Maybe it's caused by Eclipse...

Comment: Well, this behaviour is really strange. So I would like to see the code if there isn't any suspicious code. Otherwise I don't know how to solve this... But if you think that Eclipse causes it, try to create a simple Maven Project instead of this horrible thing you have there...