# External jar found in Maven Web Application but not when being deployed

Tags: maven, web-applications, netbeans, glassfish, pom.xml

I recently created a Maven Web Application through Netbeans 7.3, using GlassFish 3.1.2. In this I use an external jar, so I added it in pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>be-fedict-eid-trust-service-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>eid-trust-service-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RC5</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
</dependencies>
```

It shows up correctly and I can refer it in my Bean. BUT when I deploy the application, I get an error that the class in the jar (which I referred to without problems before) can not be found.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: be/fedict/trust/xkms2/XKMSServiceFactory
```

Since I'm not that familiar with Maven, I don't know how and where I can fix this. Looking at the generated WAR file, the jar is there correctly. I set addClasspath to true so it is in the Classpath of the Manifest, but this doesn't seem to help.

My libraries are in WEB-INF/lib and my Bean is in WEB-INF/classes.

Any thoughts or general directions to what this problem may be? I found this topic: [Spring Web App with Maven dependency - class not found during deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448852/spring-web-app-with-maven-dependency-class-not-found-during-deploy)
but I don't see how I can make it work for me (assuming he found a solution).

Thanks in advance!

**My full pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ISB</groupId>
    <artifactId>eID</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>eID</name>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>e-contract</id>
            <url>https://www.e-contract.be/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>be-fedict-eid-applet</groupId>
            <artifactId>eid-applet-shared</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RC2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>be.fedict.eid-applet</groupId>
            <artifactId>eid-applet-service</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RC2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>be-fedict-eid-applet</groupId>
            <artifactId>eid-applet-service-spi</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RC2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>be-fedict-eid-applet</groupId>
            <artifactId>eid-applet-package</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RC2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>be-fedict-eid-trust-service-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>eid-trust-service-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RC5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>be-fedict-eid-applet</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>eid-applet-package</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.1.0.RC2</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactID}</outputDirectory>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Not a Glassfish expert, that said I would check to see if there is a version of that library built into Glassfish (or at least, in a library directory used by your team's specific installation).  If so, your app may be using the one that is provided by the container instead of the one you referenced in the POM.

Comment: I now added the "eid-trust-service-client" to the <build> part of pom.xml as an artifactItem like the "be-fedict-eid-package" is done, set the dependency of it on provided and removed the jar locally (so that it gets downloaded when deploying), but the class still can't be found.
Or do you mean something else? Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure it has anything to do with your POM.  I suspect it's the libraries used in the target container (Glassfish) -- a classpath issue.  Each container does classloading a little differently.  [This question & answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2513635/944849) might give you some ideas.  If there are two, different versions of this artifact, one in container, one in your POM, you will have to tell the container which to use.  WebLogic uses a `weblogic.xml` file for this.

Comment: Ok, adding the lib to my Glassfish folder did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it has anything to do with your POM. I suspect it's the libraries used in the target container (Glassfish) -- a classpath issue. Each container does classloading a little differently. [This question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2513635/944849) might give you some ideas. If there are two, different versions of this artifact, one in container, one in your POM, you will have to tell the container which to use. WebLogic uses a weblogic.xml file for this.